# Can I use supabase in pure js (without React, NodeJS etc.)

Tags: javascript, html, css, supabase

I have to do a simple project where I use Supabase. I have just index.html, style.css, script.js, and server.php files. Can I use Supabase without installing any other libraries, packages, etc? I shouldn't use them (I do why that's just what my teacher said but I must use any database).
I tried to add `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@supabase/supabase-js@2"></script>` on the top of my HTML file but there is an error in console *Uncaught ReferenceError: createClient is not defined
at HTMLDocument. (script.js:84:18)*
I use LiveServer in VsCode to check my page.

html:`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Webcam & Images</h1>
    <div id="supabase-images">
      <!-- Контейнер для отображения картинок из Supabase -->
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>Add Your Image</h2>
      <input type="file" id="file-input">
      <button id="add-image-btn">Add Image</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>Take Snapshot</h2>
      <video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
      <button id="capture-btn">Capture</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@supabase/supabase-js@2"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>

</html>
```

js:

```
async function loadSupabaseImages() {
    const { data, error } = await supabase
        .from('images')
        .select('url');
    if (error) {
        console.error('Error loading images from Supabase:', error.message);
        return;
    }

    const container = document.getElementById('supabase-images');
    container.innerHTML = '';
    if (data && data.length > 0) {
        data.forEach(image => {
            const img = document.createElement('img');
            img.src = image.url;
            container.appendChild(img);
        });
    }
}

async function addImageToSupabase(file) {
    const { data, error } = await supabase
        .storage
        .from('images')
        .upload(file.name, file);
    if (error) {
        console.error('Error uploading image to Supabase:', error.message);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Image uploaded successfully:', data);
    loadSupabaseImages();
}

async function deleteImageFromSupabase(url) {
    const filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    const { error } = await supabase
        .storage
        .from('images')
        .remove([filename]);
    if (error) {
        console.error('Error deleting image from Supabase:', error.message);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Image deleted successfully');
    loadSupabaseImages();
}

function captureImage() {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = 640;
    canvas.height = 480;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
    canvas.toBlob(async blob => {
        const file = new File([blob], 'snapshot.png');
        await addImageToSupabase(file);
    }, 'image/png');
}

document.getElementById('file-input').addEventListener('change', event => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    if (file) {
        addImageToSupabase(file);
    }
});

document.getElementById('capture-btn').addEventListener('click', captureImage);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    // Инициализация Supabase
    const supabaseUrl = 'myurl';
const supabaseKey = 'mykey';
const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseKey);
    loadSupabaseImages();
});
```

Can I use superbase in pure js?

Comment: can you share your whole index.html? does the error occur when you try to use the library or just by importing it?

Comment: Added html and js code

Comment: first I would not use the live server in vscode to try it, as it might be restricted in what it can load. also try to convert your code to a module and import supabase into it instead of using a script tag to import it. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules to find out how.